# Set the spacing above group in a Legend - PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, legend, layouts

I am in the process of creating a script which needs to add a caption to an already existing layout.

So I created a PyQGIS code in order to do it :

```
legend = QgsLayoutItemLegend(layout)
layout.addLayoutItem(legend)
        
legend.setLinkedMap(map) # pass a QgsLayoutItemMap object

legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
#legend.adjustBoxSize()
legend.setResizeToContents(False)

legend.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(3.5, 12, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
legend.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(5.5, 2, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutCentimeters))

legend.setLineSpacing(15)
legend.setSymbolHeight(6)

#legend.setSpacingAboveGroups(15)
```

The legend is displayed well but I would like there to be space before the different groups of the legend.

I saw that this was possible in the layout editor (screenshot) but after studying the documentation for `QgsLayoutItemLegend`, I can't find a "`setSpacingAboveGroups()`" method that would allow this value to be modified. (`setSpacingAboveGroups` does not exist, this is an example)

[image]

How can I change the distance between groups in the legend using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `rstyle` method of `legend`. It returns reference to `QgsLegendStyle` object for legend components. Then, you can add spacing using `setMargin` function. Documentation for [`rstyle`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemLegend.html#a650e74518f755211dc05703a06d50f83) and [`setMargin`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLegendStyle.html#a5c3ca507174178e100ba6b546c117d95).

```
legend.rstyle(QgsLegendStyle.Group).setMargin(QgsLegendStyle.Top, 10) # Top side, 10 mm
```